# invisible/hide many2one record value when changing condition

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

how to set field record to invisible from field bank_from_journal_id when changing company_id.

```
bank_from_journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', domain="[('type', 'in', ('bank', 'cash'))]",string="Bank From", tracking=True)
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', string='Company', tracking=True,default=lambdaself: self.env.company.id)
```

Like example, i create 'bank xxx' for 'tesla company' and then i want to make bank xxx invisible/hide when changing to another company. So the bank record is only appeared when company is same as where bank record created and hide when changing to another company.

Thanks

Comment: There is a [company_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/models/account_journal.py#L119) field in account journal which you can use in `bank_from_journal_id` domain (XML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a domain on bank_from_journal_id based on company_id field.
You have two choices in order to achieve this.

First option:

Define a domain in view for bank_from_journal_id field.

```
<field name="company_id" />
<field name="bank_from_journal_id" domain="[('company_id','=',company_id)]" />
```

Second option:

Update domain when company_id changes.

**Note**: this is deprecated from odoo 15.0

```
@api.onchange('company_id')
def _onchange_company_id(self):
  self.ensure_one()
  return {'domain': {'bank_from_journal_id': [('company_id','=', self.company_id.id)]}}
```

Comment: `self.company_id` is a recordset!

Comment: I've changed `self.company_id` to `self.company_id.id`, thank you @Kenly